# JavaCC: How to parse characters that may not be exist?

Tags: parsing, javacc

I am trying to adapt a PDDL parser and there is a token that is optional to be exist. Suppose these are 2 options I want to read. 
(figure1)

```
(node1)
(node1 :isGood)               // :isGood is optional to be exist
```

To support both situations, I developed code in .jj like this figure2 below. It works correctly; however, it is an inappropriate way to write like this.
(figure2)

```
<LEFT_BRACKET>
<NODE>
(LOOKAHEAD(2) <IS_GOOD> <RIGHT_BRACKET> | <RIGHT_BRACKET>)
```

The code in .jj that I actually want it to be should be like in this figure3 below. From figure3, it parses from .jj successfully but it is unable to parse the scripts in the figure1 from which I received `unexpected token ")"` instead. (figure3)

```
<LEFT_BRACKET>
<NODE>
(LOOKAHEAD(2) <IS_GOOD>)      // this is where it should support an optional token
<RIGHT_BRACKET>
```

**Question:** How to write the code in .jj to support both conditions in figure1? In other words, how to make it support the optional token `:isGood` that may not be exist with an appropriate approach of programming.

I probably don't know how the LOOKAHEAD works. Any solution to read the figure1 is appreciate.

Comment: Isn't it just `(<IS_GOOD>) ?`?

Comment: That does not work in this case. However, I got my answer now by just changing the parenthesis to square ones. That part will look like this >> `[LOOKAHEAD(2) <IS_GOOD>]`. This code states that "if there is <IS_GOOD> then access into it, otherwise skip it. I appreciate your help and I will leave this question for other people. Anyway, I still don't quite sure about how the LOOKAHEAD works.

Comment: You don't need the lookahead specification in this case.  Just use `...[ <IS_GOOD> ] <RIGHT_BRACKET>` or `...( <IS_GOOD> )? <RIGHT_BRACKET>`.

Comment: @lexicore Sorry, you are right and that code works. I just noticed that there is  ` ?` behind your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the lookahead specification in this case. Just use

```
<LEFT_BRACKET>
<NODE>
[ <IS_GOOD> ]
<RIGHT_BRACKET>
```

or

```
<LEFT_BRACKET>
<NODE>
( <IS_GOOD> )?
<RIGHT_BRACKET>
```

or

```
<LEFT_BRACKET>
<NODE>
( <IS_GOOD> | {} )
<RIGHT_BRACKET>
```

They mean the same thing.

Comment: However, these are quite difficult to find, and I tried many solutions to learn LOOKAHEAD... still couldn't quite sure about it much. Please could you explain what does LOOKAHEAD affect my example?

Comment: I think if you add a `LOOKAHEAD(2)` specification, it means that the parser should use a lookahead of up to 2 tokens.  Since this example only needs 1 token, I suspect that adding the `LOOKAHEAD(2)` will make no difference in this case.  Why not try an experiment. Generate code with and without the lookahead specification and compare the generated java code.  My guess is it will be the same in both cases.

Comment: As to being "difficult to find", the first two are in the "grammar file" documentation. The last is in the FAQ.